# Mercurial error: repository is unrelated

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, bitbucket

I've just started with Mercurial, I have a 'central' repository on Bitbucket which I cloned onto one machine and made changes and committed and pushed. I then cloned from Bitbucket to another machine committed and pushed which was fine. I then came back to the first machine, made changes committed and attempted to push, but got the error message. What am I doing wrong? Should I have pulled first? How can I resolve the error and push? Any help is appreciated!

Darren.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A Mercurial repository gets its identity when you make the first commit in it. When you create a new repository on Bitbucket, you create an empty repository with no identity.

When you clone this repository to machine A and make a commit and push it back, then you brand the repository. If you have cloned the repository on the second machine *before* pushing from the first, then you can end up in the situation you describe.

Please run `hg paths` on the machine where you cannot push. Then make a separate clone of the repository it says it will push to. Now examine the first changeset in each repository with

```
hg log -r 0
```

If the initial changesets are different, then you have two unrelated repositories, as we call it in Mercurial. You can then export the changes you cannot push as patches and import them in the other.

Comment: That must be it, I didn't push from the first machine. So I'm guessing I need to clone from Bitbucket back to machine A, and get rid of the old one.

I take it I can work the way I am doing, on two machines, and this is just because I essentially had two revision zeros?

Comment: Yes, I think you created two unrelated repositories by accident by making two different zero revisions. After you make the first commit and push it back to Bitbucket, then you can of course keep working on two machines.

Comment: We had a similar issue and the only solution was to start over forking and cloning again. It happened because we didn't initialize the main repository and there was not any way to fix it.

Comment: what do you mean "run hg paths"? how can I execute this?

Comment: @leegod: Mercurial has a `paths` command, just like it has a `commit` and  a `status` command. So open a terminal and run `hg paths` from within the working copy of your repository.

Answer (score 3):

If you're pretty sure the push path is correct, it may be worth it to just export your changes to patches from the problem repo, clone again from Bitbucket and then import the patches into the new repo. This will either just work or reveal a bad/corrupted commit.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share knowledge about Mercurial internals.

Repositories unrelated when they have no any same revisions.

Corresponding piece you can find in `mercurial/treediscovery.py`:

```
base = list(base)
if base == [nullid]:
    if force:
        repo.ui.warn(_("warning: repository is unrelated\n"))
    else:
        raise util.Abort(_("repository is unrelated"))
```

`base` is a list of roots of common parts in both local/remote repositories.

You always may know how repositories are different by:

```
$ hg in $REMOTE
$ hg out $REMOTE
```

You always may checks roots of both (after cloning both locally):

```
$ hg -R $ONE log -r "roots(all())"
$ hg -R $TWO log -r "roots(all())"
```

if output from above commands doesn't share IDs - those repositories are unrelated. Due to **hash** properties it is very impossible that roots be equal accidentally. You may not trick roots checking by carefully crafting repositories because building two repositories looks like these (with common parts but different roots):

```
0 <--- SHA-256-XXX <--- SHA-256-YYY <--- SHA-256-ZZZ
0 <--- SHA-256-YYY <--- SHA-256-ZZZ
```

impossible because that mean you reverse SHA-256 as each subsequent hash depends on previous values.

Having this info I believe any Devs be able to troubleshoot `error: repository is unrelated`.

See also [Mercurial repository identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307358/mercurial-repository-identification/)

Thanks for attention, good hacking!

Answer (score 1):

You get this message when you try to push to a repository other than the one that you cloned.  Double-check the address of the push, or the `default` path, if you're just using `hg push` by itself.

To check the default path, you can use `hg showconfig | grep ^paths\.default` (or just `hg showconfig` and look for the line that starts `paths.default=`).

Comment: It's definitely the same one, I only the one on Bitbucket.

Comment: Did you do anything funky, like running `hg convert` on it?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I didn't. I've been using SourceTree and have literally only done a commit and push on both machines.