# Is there a Mercurial (hg) equivalent of `git remote -v`?

Tags: mercurial

That is, does Mercurial have a command to tell where it was originally cloned from?

The following question seems to not serve that purpose: [Mercurial repository identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307358/mercurial-repository-identification)

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall special command for it, just because I always read repo's hgrc `[paths]` section by eye due to fact (`hg help config`)

> ```
> The following special named paths exist:
>
> "default"
>    The URL or directory to use when no source or remote is specified.
>
>    'hg clone' will automatically define this path to the location the
>    repository was cloned from.
> ```

but if you want hg command **and trust** hgrc's content (which can be edited at any time), you can use `hg config paths.default` which output key from repo-config, without warranties of using *this URL* for the whole lifetime of repo